# How to create something similar to google style currency converter with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Ok I have a bit of a weird question here. I have a program similar to a currency converter (it performs a mathematical function in order to produce a value to go in another textbox). What I want it to be able to do is identify the last textbox that you edited (there are 4) and then update the rest based on what you have inputted, the user then must be able to change a different textbox to change all of them.

If anyone can get me started on how to do it or even some sample code that would be much appreciated, thanks!

Sorry if I'm not making sense, just have a look at the google currency converter and think that with two more editable boxes.

Comment: Just have a look at [ask] and the [tour] for how to post questions here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want if I understand you correctly.

In the form class, you have a variable called `lastTextBoxChangedName` which keeps track of which text box was the last to be edited.

Next there is an event handler which will fire when any of the four TextBoxes are changed. This merely updates `lastTextBoxChangedName`.

When you have finihed editing a textbox, and tab to the next one or click on something that causes a TextBox to lose input focus, the next event handler executes. This looks at `lastTextBoxChangedName` to see which was the last edited TextBox and you can insert your update code to replace the comments in the `Select Case` block.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim lastTextBoxChangedName As String

    Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox4.TextChanged
        lastTextBoxChangedName = sender.name
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus, TextBox3.LostFocus, TextBox4.LostFocus
        updateTextBoxes()
    End Sub

    Private Sub updateTextBoxes()
        Select Case lastTextBoxChangedName
            Case "TextBox1"
                'do updates appropriate to textbox1 changed
            Case "TextBox2"
                'do updates appropriate to textbox2 changed
            Case "TextBox3"
                'do updates appropriate to textbox3 changed
            Case "TextBox4"
                'do updates appropriate to textbox4 changed
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, if you already have separate event handlers for each TextBox, don't add that first event handler for `TextBox_TextChanged`, just add the line ..

```
lastTextBoxChangedName = sender.name
```

into each handler.